# ParallelTable never ends on simple ContourPlot loop

Tags: parallelization

**Context**

I am interested in solving [Transient Gray Scott](https://www.wolfram.com/language/12/nonlinear-finite-elements/transient-gray-scott-model.html?product=language) equations.
Following the documentation:

I define the equations

```
eqn0 = {Derivative[1, 0, 0][u][t,x,y] + 
           Inactive[Div][(-c1)*Inactive[Grad][
                 u[t, x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] +
   (v[t,x,y]^2 + f)*u[t,x,y] == f, 
       Derivative[1, 0, 0][v][t,x,y] + 
           Inactive[Div][(-c2)*Inactive[Grad][
                 v[t, x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] +
     ((-u[t,x,y])*v[t,x,y] + f + k)*
             v[t,x,y] == 0}; 
eqn = eqn0 //. {c1 -> 2/10^5, c2 -> c1/4, f -> 1/25, k -> 3/50};
```

The initial conditions

```
ics = {u[0,x,y] == 1/2, v[0,x,y] == If[x^2+y^2 <= 1/40, 1, 0]};
```

The boundary conditions

```
bcs = DirichletCondition[{u[t,x,y] == 0, v[t,x,y] == 0}, True];
```

Then I solve

```
{ufun, vfun} = 
  NDSolveValue[{eqn, bcs, ics}, {u,v}, {x,y} \[Element] Disk[], {t, 
    0, 500}, 
   Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"MethodOfLines", 
       "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
         "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.003}}}}];
```

And make plots

```
{vmin, vmax} = MinMax[vfun["ValuesOnGrid"]];
frames = Table[ ContourPlot[vfun[t,x,y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
    Sequence[Contours -> Range[vmin, vmax, (vmax - vmin)/4], 
     PlotRange -> All, Frame -> None, Axes -> None, 
     PlotStyle -> ColorData["Heat"]]], {t, 25, 500, 15}];    
ListAnimate[frames]
```

[image]

So far so good.
But, since I have 8 cores on my computer I thought naively I could accelerate
the frame production by  replacing `Table` by `ParallelTable` in  `frames = Table[`

**Problem**

When I do this the run never ends while all CPUs are running at 99 %.

I am using Mathematica 12.1 on MacOS 10.15.6.

**Question**

> Why does consumes endless amount of CPU?

This problem is directly from the documentation.
It would be really useful to be able to gain a factor of 8
in speed in this last (boring) step :-)

Comment: Comparing `ParallelEvaluate@Print@RepeatedTiming@vfun[25, 0, 0]` with `Print@RepeatedTiming@vfun[25, 0, 0]` it looks like the evaluation of the `InterpolatingFunction` `vfun` in a parallel kernel is about 3000 times slower than in the main kernel, which explains why `ContourPlot` never finishes.

Comment: @Hausdorff Thanks for the timing. Any idea why?